# Generating 14V, 12V, and 5V for winbond 8051 chips such as w77e58

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, transistors, voltage-regulator, voltage-divider

I'm trying to make a way without error to use the fewest digital inputs possible to provide an output of 14V, 12V and 5V on the VPP pin of the winbond microcontroller. The model I will be using is w77e58.

I have seen circuits that only produce 5 and 12V but none for 14V.

The circuit below is my attempt. and the regulator on the bottom right is one the rest of the circuitry. Capacitors will be 22uF/50v electrolytic.

I have calculated the resistors the best I can based on what's available at the local store to achieve the required voltages.

The only issue I have with this particular circuit is that if all inputs to every transistor is logic low then the output will get 15V which might blow up the microcontroller (for being 1V over at the VPP pin)

How do I improve this circuit so my issue no longer exists regardless of the digital input? and it would be ideal if I convered the separate inputs for 12V to 14V to one exclusive input since I won't need both those voltages at the same time.

I also have PNP transistors if that helps.

[image: circuit]

Comment: You better evaluate the current draw on the VPP pin. The high value resistors in your dividers will not keep your expected voltage when there is a load current.... especially if that load is not constant. Also you need series resistors in the base of the transistors.

Comment: I needed 13.5V for Vpp on a device. I simply used a digital pin from the MCU to boost Vcc up. ADC told me when it settled in. Each inductor pulse added a small bit of energy to the cap. It wasn't hard, at all. After programming a byte, I'd recharge the cap and then program another byte. Works fine and can target various Vpp values, too.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better to use a an LM317 and resistors on the ADJ pin to select a regulated voltage that will not be unduly affected by loading.

I looked for a similar circuit, and this one from Ed Nisley's [blog](https://softsolder.com/2009/07/07/simpleminded-eprom-programming-power-supply/) that also has a switch + clamp with active-high input that meets your other requirement:

[image]

It should be easy for you to figure out from the LM317 [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf) how to fiddle the resistor values and add a transistor + resistor to get the third voltage, but ask if you have any issues. Leave the 220 ohms as-is and change the other parts (R6, R7 and add one more resistor and another transistor).

You can take the 5V regulator input from the 18V supply.

Comment: Is there a BJT transistor equivalent to this circuit? I don't own mosfets

Comment: It's not critical- use any old general purpose NPN transistor such as C8050, C1815, MMBT4401, BC547, 2N3904 , whatever but add suitable series base resistors, obviously, and account for a bit of Vce(sat) rather than Rds(on) to hit the voltage bang-on.